# How to resume child fragments on parent fragment resume

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment called the `MainFragment` with a `TabLayout`. The `TabLayout` has two tabs with a fragment each. Lets call it `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`.

When I open the `MainFragment`, `Fragment A` and `Fragment B` are populated within the `TabLayout` as expected. When I resume `MainFragment`, `Fragment A` and `Fragment B` are not resumed, and I get two empty tabs.

My `MainFragment` looks like this

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Injector.component().inject(this);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA(), "Fragment A");
        adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB(), "Fragment B");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Paste your Activity code which hosts MainFragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Fragments `A` & `B` are child fragments of `MainFragment`, use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`